# I added navigation to my kotlin andriod app but when I added it, my app crashes in the emulator

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I added navigation to an android (kotlin) app. After putting my homescreen as the start destination and later running the app, the app won't open and the emulator says my app keeps stopping. The HomeScreen() function is contains the design of the screen. I used the implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10").

I want the app the launch, with the HomeScreen to be the start destination.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.Ex.ui.theme.ExTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ExTheme{

                navController = rememberNavController()
                SetupNavGraph(navController = navController)

            }
        }
    }
}
----------------------------------------------------------------
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable


@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Home.route
    ){
        composable(
            route = Screen.Home.route
        ){
            HomeScreen()
        }
    }
}
--------------------------------------------------------
sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object Home: Screen(route = "home_screen")
    object Detail: Screen(route = "detail_screen")
}
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha10")
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Navigation 2.4.0-alpha10? There's been [33 releases since then](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation), including the latest stable version of 2.6.0.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I think the issue is with the gradle version, I updated it and it seemed to work. What is the purpose of gradle and gradle implementation in the first place?

Comment: You never included the error message, so it is impossible to tell what the issue you are facing actually is.